# Minimum possible jumps needed to reach (m-1,n-1) from (0,0) in a 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, graph-algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

A 2D array of size m X n. Imagine a cat in first slot (0,0). The elements of the the array indicate the longest possible jump from that slot. For Example: the current slot contains 3, the cat can jump to the 3rd slot/2nd slot/1st slot, horizontally or vertically. The cat cannot jump diagonally. The cat cannot land on the slot containing 0. From a '0 slot' the cat cannot move anywhere. I must write a java program to find the minimum possible jumps from (0,0) to (m-1,n-1).

What data structure should I use ? 
               I guess a data structure which can store multiple paths with nodes between starting & ending nodes, like graph.
What algorithm should I follow ? 
               I guess shortest path algorithm like dijkstra's shouls be modified according to this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortest path in a grid between two points. With a catch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158304/shortest-path-in-a-grid-between-two-points-with-a-catch)

Comment: maybe dynamic programming, with backtracking

Answer (score 0):

From what I got from your question, you can only move horizontally or vertically.

`"the current slot contains 3, the cat can jump to the 3rd slot, horizontally or vertically.`

Since it can not move diagonally, the shortest path is the either path. One way or another, from (1,3), to get to (2,5) you still end up going down one and over 2, the order doesn't matter.

If you CAN move diagonally, have you tried using the Pythagorean Theorem? `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`.

```
//A = amount of vertical jumps, B = amount of horizonal jumps, C = the distance in-between.
//Prior to this, you'd have to know the point you are going to.
```

From there, take the square root of `c^2` and remove the decimal part.

i.e. `Math.sqrt(2) = 1.414  //just keep the 1`

To keep the 1, you could set it to round down if there is a decimal, this will ensure that you always get the correct number of diagonal jumps.

That will take you as far diagonally as you can go, then just complete the jump with whatever you can do (i.e. horizontal or vertical).

Comment: We cannot jump diagonally. I have written down the problem more clearly. Kindly read again and help me.